# Video files in mpeg2 format on website

Tags: php, video, mpeg-2

I am working on a client's website. I am in a search of video player that could play the mpeg2 videos without having any problem. I have all video files of very heavy size so how can i compress the file size before playing or user downloading in php . If any one can suggest a best video player.

Comment: Convert it to mpeg4 or other web browser compatible formats. So you can choose between lot of different HTML5 players.

Comment: but it takes very long time i have thousands of videos. any other idea?

Comment: Is it mpeg2 codec, or mpeg2 container? What codec is the audio? I highly doubt you will find a reasonable solution without transcoding.

Comment: its mpeg2 codec. and its video files not audio files